# How do I install screen on RHEL6.5

Tags: software-installation, yum

I'm having trouble trying to install `screen` on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6.5.

I have tried:

```
sudo yum install screen
```

Also...

```
sudo yum install screen.x86_64
```

Running...

```
sudo yum list screen
```

yields...

> Error: No matching Packages to list

Running `sudo yum repolist` gave me this:

> Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
>
> This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
>
> Repository 'DVD' is missing name in configuration, using id
>
> repo id                   repo name                                       status
>
> pgdg93                    PostgreSQL 9.3 6Server - x86_64                   407
>
> rpmforge                  RHEL 6Server - RPMforge.net - dag               4,718
>
> rpmforge-extras           RHEL 6Server - RPMforge.net - extras              711
>
> repolist: 5,836

When I run `sudo subscription-manager list`, I get:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
    Installed Product Status
+-------------------------------------------+
Product Name:   Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
Product ID:     69
Version:        6.5
Arch:           x86_64
Status:         Unknown
Status Details:
Starts:
Ends:
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: What does `yum repolist` show?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn Updated the question with results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you don't have a Red Hat subscription and are unable to get updates from Red Hat without one.

See [this answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/537568/do-i-need-a-rhel-subscription-to-install-packages) for more details.

If this is a licensed version of Red Hat, then [this information on the Red Hat website shows you how to register your subscription](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-steps-rhnreg-x86.html).

If this is a new server installation you may want to consider switching to CentOS, which is the community supported version of Red Hat Enterprise Linux, or Fedora Server.